# Solidity | fixed data type of variable for transferring custom token (erc20)

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm using simple transfer function like below.

```
  function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal {                
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value); // Subtract from the sender
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value); // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
}
```

The token amount of argument is received as `uint256` data type so that I can't transfer the custom token as `float` data type even I deployed my token as `18 Decimals`. For example, I want to transfer the amount of token like `0.00001, 0.00000002`. I noticed the `ufixed` data type currently on Solidity 0.4.21 but I can't test on Remix with 0.4.21 version and `fixed` type. How can I transfer my token with `ufixed` data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your token has 18 decimal places then "one token" is represented by the number 1000000000000000000. (A one with 18 zeros after it.)

So to transfer 0.00001 tokens, you would use the number 10000000000000.